# Cassandra cluster bulk loader hangs during export

Tags: cassandra

I am migrating a simple 4 node Cassandra cluster from one cloud provider to another. The number of nodes in both the clouds are same however the newer cluster is at version 3.11.0 and the older one is at  3.0.11. I am using `sstableloader` to stream data from one cluster to another (schema has been created on new cluster separately). As per the release [notes](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt) this should not be a problem.

However, for certain column families with `sstableloader` I get progress to 100% but then it hangs there for hours (time hang >> time to stream). The total data to stream on each node is below 500 GB. Any help on why this is happening and how to avoid is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new node and add to the existing cluster from the new cloud server

[Flush tables from the memtable to SSTables on disk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsFlush.html#toolsFlush)

Delete one node from old cloud server. Like wise repeat for each node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This technique works when you want to bridge clusters for migration. Something of a last resort as it is advised to have same versions of cassandra when adding datacenter(s). My OP is best practices/pitfalls of Cassandra bulk loader.